# Can you play minecraft multiplayer on one account using one computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to play minecraft on one account, using one computer?

My friend and I want to play together, but she dosent have a computer.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, this is not possible. You might get away with the one account thing, but not the one computer. Minecraft requires a keyboard and mouse, and while it is possible to have more than one Minecraft open at a time, you cannot move with both because when you move to the other one, the one you were on goes to pause. Unless you could find some program where you could plug in 2 keyboards and 2 mouses and dedicate them to certain programs (One to each MC), than this is not feasibly possible, sorry.

Comment: There are programs doing that. For example SoftXpand. It's also possible to do it with a [virtual machine](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/237498-44-users-computer-tutorial-simplified). Otherwise there are linux distros that support multiseat configurations (I heard fedora does).

Comment: I was going to say VM, but how does that work with the mouse and keyboard? Can you dedicate 1 mouse and 1 keyboard to the regular system and 1 of each to VM? @ Dodekeract

Comment: I included a link in my comment. Apparently it's possible.